# Error from PineconeClient for node 'RequiredError: Required parameter requestParameters.upsertRequest was null or undefined when calling upsert.'

Tags: javascript, node.js, vector-database

I got error when I upsert the vectors to PineCone with PineconeClient for nodejs

the code is

```
const index = pinecone.Index("imagesindex");
const upsertRequest = {
  vectors: [
    {
      id: "vec1",
      values: [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4],
      metadata: {
        genre: "drama",
      },
    },
    {
      id: "vec2",
      values: [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5],
      metadata: {
        genre: "action",
      },
    },
  ],
  namespace: "example-namespace",
};
try {
  const upsertResponse = await index.upsert(upsertRequest);  
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

index.upsert return "RequiredError: Required parameter requestParameters.upsertRequest was null or undefined when calling upsert"

What is the correct way to index.upsert ?

Answer (score 0):

Got this from the GitHub repo of PineconeClient:

```
const upsertRequest: UpsertRequest = {
    vectors,
    namespace,
};
await index.upsert({ upsertRequest });
```

I believe you should try this:

```
try {
    const upsertResponse = await index.upsert({ upsertRequest });  
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

The field `upsertRequest` of the parameter you passed in is null. You are passing upsertRequest as `requestParameters` when you should pass it as `requestParameters.upsertRequest`